# Find the length of $LC$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> Given a quadrilateral $ABCD$ has a parallelogram $MLNK$ inscribed inside with $M,L,N,K$ lie on $AB,BC,CD,AD$ respectively with $AK=8,KD=10,BL=11$ and $AM=MB,CN=ND$. Find $LC$

[image]

Could someone one help me with this problem? I have asked before but I dun get any answer, sorry for asking again. I get this problem from [Here](https://mundogeometria.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/457/)

Comment: Any thoughts? Similar triangles?

Comment: @Andrei doesn't seem to have any similar Triangle to me. I think the solution might involved coordinate geometry

Comment: @user635988 If Lion Heart's answer solves your question then accept that, please.

Comment: @S.H.W I'm taking sometime to understand the solution and see if there is any other solution. Sorry for late response

Comment: @user635988 No problem. Good luck!

Comment: @S.H.W I wonder if all quadrilateral could have at least 2 parallelogram inscribed inside it, or just for some that is possible

Comment: @user635988 I think for every quadrilateral there are infinitely many inscribed parallelograms. See the endgameendgame's comment on the mentioned page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P$ and $Q$ the midpoint of $AD$ and $BC$,  respectively.
quadrilateral $MPNQ$ is a parallelogram.
triangle $KMP$ and triangle $LNQ$ are congruent triangles.
Hence, $QL=KP=1$ and $BQ=CQ=10$ and $CL=9$. Here is the construction which have created using GeoGebra:

[image]
This is a relevant [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804937/inscribed-parallelogram-in-a-quadrilateral) which might be interesting.

Comment: Why are triangle KMP and triangle LNQ congruent?

Comment: KM=LN and MP=NQ (opposisite side of parallelogram)   anglePMN=angleQNM, angle KMN=angle LNM(alt. int. ang.), angle KMP = angle KMN - angle PMN = angle LNM - angle QNM = angle LNQ. triangle KMP is congruent to triangle LNQ (S.A.S congruence theorem).

Comment: how do we know that point Q is between B and L and not between C and L ? The scale of the drawing is not accurate since it shows AD = 18 as greater than BC=20

Comment: The scale is not important. Since angle KMP and angle LNQ are angles with parallel sides in opposite directions, point Q is between B and L.

Comment: Did I miss any detail in this solution

Comment: @LionHeart Your solution seems fine but I couldn't draw that construction in GeoGebra with trial and error. Obviously connecting midpoints consecutively, forms a parallelogram but actually is it possible to inscribe other parallelograms inside a quadrilateral?

Comment: @LionHeart This answer shows that is possible: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804937/inscribed-parallelogram-in-a-quadrilateral So I think your solution is fine(+1).

Comment: @S.H.W So we did a good work.

Comment: @LionHeart Certainly you solved the question nicely. I've added some details to your answer. Feel free to edit that.