# Inscribed parallelogram in a quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers, analytic-geometry

It's well known that consecutively connecting midpoints of an arbitrary quadrilateral forms a parallelogram. Is it possible to inscribe other parallelograms inside a quadrilateral? I didn't find an example for that, so tried to come up with some argument which shows that parallelogram is unique but didn't get result. After that I used complex numbers to describe the problem. Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral with points $M$, $P$,$N$ and $Q$ on its sides. Also $MPNQ$ is a parallelogram.
[image: Drawn by Geogebra] So we have

$$\cases{\frac{A - M}{A^* - M^*}= \frac{M - B}{M^* - B^*} \\
   \frac{A - P}{A^* - P^*} = \frac{P - D}{P^* - D^*} \\
   \frac{D - N}{D^* - N^*} = \frac{N - C}{N^* - C^*} \\
   \frac{C - Q}{C^* - Q^*} = \frac{Q - B}{Q^* - B^*} \\
   M - Q + N - P = 0 }$$

I don't know how to proceed further.

Comment: Do you consider a line as a degenerated parallelogram?

Comment: @Anand No by a parallelogram I mean a quadrilateral with two pairs of parallel sides.

Comment: we can inscribe infinite  number of parallelograms in a quadrilateral parallel to its diagonals

Comment: @endgameendgame Would you show some examples, please?

Comment: draw diagonals of of the quadrilateral then  draw a line segment parallel to one of the diagonals. connect the line segment with onother line parallel to the diagonals. repeat  the process and you get a parallelogram... you can prove this with thales theorem

Comment: @endgameendgame I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering you are interested in the following question:

> Can we say that a parallelogram is inscribed in a quadrilateral if and only if it is formed by joining the mid-points of sides of the quadrilateral.

The above statement is not true. For instance, consider the following construction:

Draw two squares $ABCD$ and $A'B'C'D'$. Consider the quadrilateral formed by $$\{AA'\cap BB',BB'\cap CC',CC'\cap DD', DD'\cap AA'\}$$This quadrilateral will obviously have at least two distinct parallelogram (more precisely squares).

[image]

Comment: Would you give an image for this construction, please? I couldn't follow that.

Comment: @S.H.W I've added the image for your kind reference.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anand, you started from squares. Can one start from any given quadrilateral and then find parallelograms or/and squares (apart from the medial parallelogram ofcourse)?

Comment: @cosmo we can find  many parellelograms  in any quadrilateral but  in general we cannot inscribe a square in a quadrilateral (eg. rectangle)